# Three collinear points A, B & C make lines. Line AB , line BC & line AC are considered as three different coincident lines or one line with 3 names?

Tags: geometry

If we have three points let say A , B and C they are collinear. The lines created with these three points are $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ , $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ . What is correct they are three different coincident lines or single line with three different names.

We can consider plane is filled with points and line is considered if we select points from the plane (line is subset of plane), similarly other objects. Using this analogy how can we say these are three different lines because these are same points (subset) of the plane it should be single line with three different names. Using incident geometry these are three different coincident lines. Then how these lines think intuitively using incident geometry (which is heterogenous relation between objects).

What is correct? If both are correct pls give example when first idea is useful and when second idea the useful to apply.

Thank you in advance. It is very confusing.

Comment: The statement reminds me of Pasch's axiom: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasch%27s_axiom

Comment: The axiom is used by Hilbert to prove the following proposition:
Of three aligned points A, B and C, there is one which is between the other two.

Comment: Hello Tiler , Pls explain this according to my question and thank you for your help. Hilbert in this sense use this axiom to show betweeness.

Comment: I'd say this is mostly a matter of point of view and what your definition of line is. In analytic geometry, for instance, a line is a *set* of points whose coordinates satisfy a certain equation. In this sense, two lines being the same means that the sets are the same, thought the equations can differ. In a synthetic geometric, that is, one derived from axioms, it really depends on what you define your lines to be. But even in the synthetic case, any sensible model for your geometry would have lines as a set of points (since points are "contained" in lines), so coincidence would be "equality".

Comment: Thanks for much better answer @DouglasFinamore . which is exactly what i thought. Pls explain more specific to my question. My question is specifically about synthetic geometry. You mean $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ , $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ are one single line not three but have three different names. If case of two intersecting lines , the point of intersection is single coincident point for both lines? Is it correct.

Comment: If it is *any* synthetic geometry then it depends your definition of a line. To bring this more down to earth, let's think of a specific synthetic approach to Euclidean geometry: [Hilbert's description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms). In this case, his lines are fundamental objects, which are not defined, and they satisfy another fundamental property, an incidence relation, which states that points can be cointained in lines. Then he states an axiom that says that given two points there is a *unique* line containing both, so in this case your coincident lines are the same.

Comment: What is important here is uniqueness. Hilbert clearly states that through any two points passes a unique line. So $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ , $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ need to be necessarily the same. In his Elements, Euclides never says in the axioms that the line through two points is unique, though he uses uniquess implicilty in his arguments. For a general synthetic geometry, it really depends on the axioms.

Comment: What about points in which unique line passes. Does these two given points also belong to the points of line (subset of line). I am here asking about synthetic Euclidean geometry. Pls read this link https://www.sfu.ca/~swartz/euclid.htm , Axiom say "Things which coincide with one another are equal to one another." Pls confirm this also.

Comment: I think stack exchange community is not capable/interested to answer this simple and basic elementary question.

Comment: in the axiomatic system described in your link it is clearly stated that "things which coincide with one another are equal to one another", so $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$ , $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ are the same in that geometry. As for your other question, I dont understand what you mean when you write *does these two given points also belong to the points of line (subset of line).*

Comment: @DouglasFinamore I meant to say that we consider line is made up of points , So the points on the line which named by us A and B are belong to the points at which line made?